# ngrx effects - streams canceling previous streams before completing

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am stuck and could use some advice to get me pointed in the right direction. I have a store that is an array (for context: an array of charts) and each item in the array has its own state. each item is responsible for making an API an api call however when a new effect is triggered and makes an api call, it cancels the previous api call and from what i can tell cancels out the previous stream all together. any help is greatly appreciated.

The effect looks like this

> ```
> @Effect() addCharts$ = this.actions$
>     .ofType(LOAD_CHART)
>     .switchMap((action) => {
>         return this.chartApi.getChart(action.payload.url).map((res) => {
>           res.id = action.payload.id;
>           res.url = action.payload.url;
>           return res;
>         });
>     })
>     .map((result: any) => {
>         debugger;
>         return {
>           type: LOAD_CHART_SUCCESS,
>           payload: result
>         }
>     })
>     .catch((error: any) => {
>         debugger;
>         return Observable.of({
>             type: LOAD_CHART_FAILURE,
>             payload: error.detail
>         });
>     });
> ```

The end result makes my store look like this.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    data: null,
    loading: true,
    loaded: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      ...
    }
    loading: false,
    loaded: true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `mergeMap` instead (or `concatMap`, if preserving the order is important).

According to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) `switchMap`

> projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.

So each time the effect receives a `LOAD_CHART` action, it unsubscribes from any current `chartApi.getChart`, etc.